# animate if a checkbox isn't checked and a user tries to proceed

Tags: javascript, animation

This is what I have so far

```
$(document).on('click', '.signin', function() {
        if ($('#signinbox').prop('checked') == true) {
            window.location.href = '/api/login';
         }
}
```

---

What I'm trying to achieve: If a user tries to log in without checking the box, then it invokes the shake animation in `animate.css` to give them feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

If the checkbox is not checked, you can add the animated classes and then remove it after some time, like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.signin', function() {
  if ($('#signinbox').prop('checked') == true) {
    window.location.href = '/api/login';
  } else {
    $('.signin').addClass('animated shake');
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.signin').removeClass('animated shake');
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="signin">Login</button>
  <input type="checkbox" id="signinbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, it seems you're just needing a conditional. Below, I'm casting the checkbox's `checked` attribute state to a Boolean and based on that, appropriating the desired action. In particular, I'm only navigating to the login URL if it is checked. The `window.location.href` line is only hit if the checkbox is checked.

Note, I haven't actually tested this code, but this seems like the barebones structure for what you're looking for.

```
$(document).on('click', '.signin', function() {
  const $signInBox = $('#signinbox');
  if (!$signInBox.prop('checked')) {
    return $signInBox.addClass('animated shake');
  } else 
    return window.location.href = '/api/login';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the jist of what you want to do is to add the class 'shake' when the checkbox hasn't been checked and remove the class when the animation ends

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
var form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('animationend', function(e){
    e.target.classList.remove('shake');
})


document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  if(!checkbox.checked){
    form.classList.add('shake');
  } else {
    console.log('logged in!');
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o3spo0qL/